# Simple notes manager with sections

Tags: windows, note-taking

I am looking for very simple note manager that should have some feature like:

- A sidebar in which I can create sub sections of a document; preferably multi-level tree like hierarchy
- Should be very fast to load
- Good to have encryption feature but it should not be compulsory
- I don't need features like cloud syncing, cross OS support or text formatting or support for any data type except text

For inspiration of what I am looking for, see [CryptoTE](https://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/screenshot.png). It just misses support for multi level tabs and has force encryption requirement. Otherwise it is perfect.

Comment: `very fast to load` - Does it count if a software takes time to start the first time during a log-in session, but after that minimizes to system tray and starts faster?

Comment: @Timmy Yeah! I am fine with such scenarios

Comment: With sub-sections, do you mean sections (with headings) in the same document (and a table of contents in the sidebar)? Or should this be separate documents, which can be navigated from the hierarchy/menu in the sidebar (which shows all documents)?

Comment: @unor I will prefer the first case as individual document can be moved easily. But it is not very important requirement

Answer (score 1):

How about [Cherrytree](http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/#features)? Seems to have all you need:

- sidebar with multi-level tree like hierarchy (also, drag-and-drop),
- seems to be loading quite fast (at least on my machine),
- you can password protect your notes if you choose to,
- select your own type of formatting,
- runs on Windows,
- is free.