# Alternative to Evernote

Tags: windows, note-taking

I'm looking for something very similar to Evernote, the only thing I want that Evernote misses out, is sub-folder support, I can't create a sub-notebook which is ideally what I'd like. Sort of like confluence but not web-based.

I don't mind design too much as long as I have the sub-folder feature. So all I want is just a notes system with sub-folders; plain-text notes are sufficient.

Comment: Do you need online syncing?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard it doesn't have to - but if it does then great haha

Comment: Have you check out Microsoft OneNote ? This one you can sync as well.

Comment: @PROBERT sorry for long delay - I have and didn't get on with it :(

Comment: Does https://alternativeto.net/help? Specifically https://alternativeto.net/software/evernote/

Comment: Or any of the replies to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35392/an-open-alternative-for-evernote?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Cherrytree](http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/#features)? (I just recommended it in another [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22911/simple-notes-manager-with-sections/45119#45119) as it looks quite good).

- has a subfolder feature,
- is not web-based,
- quite similar to Evernote in functionalities (from my observation).

Maybe it can work for you, have a look.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out! (sorry for late reply)

Answer (score 1):

[TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/), because who doesn't want an open-sourced, powerful and visually appealing approach to notes?

Let's take a look at the features:

1. Cross-platform file tagging, annotation and finding;
2. Note taking and information management;
3. Browse folders and preview your files in one application

But further to my recommendation is supported [extensions](https://www.tagspaces.org/extensions/)- I quite often use the [ZIP viewer](https://docs.tagspaces.org/extensions/viewerZIP) for my arch backups - and there are a [few other file types you can view](https://www.tagspaces.org/supported-file-formats/).

Lastly, let's talk about the functionality:

1. Color scheme;
2. Check box, hyperlinks, highlighting and tagging by default;
3. Customization view tab

The key functions of the editor are (to me):

- Image Support;
- Code formatting for notes;
- Custom tags and search features and;
- Check Box / Table Support.

[image: Default View]

*But does it suit your needs?*

> I can't create a sub-notebook which is ideally what I'd like.

You can make as many sub-folders as you like!

> Sort of like confluence but not web-based.

All local, the way it *should be* ;)

> I don't mind design too much as long as I have the sub-folder feature.

Just wish to reiterate the fact this exists!

> plain-text notes are sufficient.

....literally any text editor passes this requirement, but this does `MD` files too! Yay Github!

Comment: Thank you I will check it out! (sorry for late reply)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs any thoughts?